# Cannot tap UIBarButtonItem in Xcode UI Test

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

My navigation bar as an "Add" button on it, and I need to have Xcode's UI test tap that button to perform tests in the view controller it opens.  I add the button programmatically like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showAddVC)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

And in my test I have:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCTAssert([app.buttons[@"Add"] exists]); // <-- This passes, so the test runner does see the button.
```

But when I try to tap it using either:

```
// Generated using the test recorder
[app.navigationBars[@"App Title"].buttons[@"Add"] tap];
```

or:

```
// Same expression used with the XCTAsset earlier
[app.buttons[@"Add"] tap];
```

Nothing happens. The action that should take place when the button is tapped does not happen.  I tried adding some `sleep(5)`'s between lines to let the app load, but that didn't help much.

This is the test log:

```
Test Case '-[xx]' started.
    t =     0.00s     Start Test
    t =     0.00s     Set Up
2015-12-22 16:25:02.898 XCTRunner[10978:384690] Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
    t =     0.94s         Launch xx
    t =     1.01s             Waiting for accessibility to load
    t =     3.45s             Wait for app to idle
    t =     9.02s     Tap "Add" Button
    t =     9.02s         Wait for app to idle
    t =    39.07s             Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - App failed to quiesce within 30s
xx: error: -[xx] : UI Testing Failure - App failed to quiesce within 30s
```

Comment: The log tells you that something else is happening on the main thread, so that the button can't be tapped. You need to think about why that is.

Comment: How would I go about testing this?  Pausing the debugger shows that Thread 1 is just the main.m call.

Comment: The assertion failure might have resulted from a bug in the framework.

Try this- before you call tap on the Add button, try to tap anywhere on the screen- the nav bar itself, for instance. Then place a breakpoint on the line after that tap statement. When you run the test and you get to that breakpoint, you can then printout the view hierarchy in LLDB. Confirm that the Add button exists in LLDB.

Based on the error statement above, I think XCTest is able to see the Add button- I don't think that's the error that's throwing you off.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers worked for me. What finally made it work, after hours of struggle, was repeating the tap. Try this:

```
[app.navigationBars[@"App Title"].buttons[@"Add"] tap];
[app.navigationBars[@"App Title"].buttons[@"Add"] tap];
```

While the above worked for me initially, I found that sometimes the first tap worked, which would result in two taps. My solution to this was to instead **tap an arbitrary UI element that doesn't trigger any actions at the beginning of the UI test**, and then proceed as normal. I think that the first tap works on certain devices, or maybe after the first UI test is run.

Comment: I should have run into this answer 48 hours ago!

Answer (score 1):

Testing for `exists` does not seem to be sufficient in your case. Wait for the button to be `hittable` before trying to tap it.

```
    expectationForPredicate(predicate, evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeoutSeconds, handler: nil)
```

Where in your case it would be:

```
    expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "hittable == YES"), evaluatedWithObject: [app.buttons[@"Add"], handler: nil)
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(15, handler: nil)
    [app.buttons[@"Add"] tap];
```

This will pause execution of code after the `waitForExpectationWithTimeout` until that predicate has been satisfied with the given element.

Otherwise, in extreme cases I have found that sometimes errors occur when trying to interact with certain components. How, why and when these occur is a bit of a mystery, but they seem to be somewhat consistent to certain components, and things involving UINavigationBars seem to have them happen more often.

To overcome these, I have found that using this extension will sometimes work.

```
extension XCUIElement {

    /* Sends a tap event to a hittable/unhittable element. Needed to get past bug */
    func forceTapElement() {
        if hittable {
            tap()
        }
        else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error @alex  
caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[XCUIElement forceTapElement]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc8451fb140"

am I doing something wrong with the extension?

Comment: @ChrisButcher it should work if you are declaring it correctly, are you declaring it at file scope in your UITest file?

Comment: yes @alex in the file scope.

    `....
    import XCTest

    extension XCUIElement {
        func forceTapElement() {
            if self.hittable {
                self.tap()
            }
            else {
               let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))
                coordinate.tap()
            }
        }
    }

    class MoreMenuTests2: XCTestCase {
    ....`

Comment: there does seem to be no rhyme or reason to it. Sometimes "exist" will just be false, even though you can clearly see the element is there. I've run the same UI test multiple times. It either all runs through fine and passes, or the exist check fails for different elements on different runs. There are obviously still some kinks in XCTest that Apple need to sort out.

Comment: I have run into the same situation with + bar button. `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` didn't help. Button is hittable and exists but single tap isn't working. But two consecutive taps work! So I ended up just with this workaround - add two taps where single tap isn't working. Killed two days looking for workaround for this test.

Answer (score 1):

For those for whom Alex's answer is not working, try this:

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTap() {
        coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5)).tap()
    }
}
```

I just had an issue with `UIWebView` which is hittable but the tap didn't work until done it via coordinate

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is your bar button item pushes a new view controller that has a refresh control - you might especially encounter this on iPads only where your bar button item pushes onto the detail part of a split view controller.  After fetching your items, you might stop your refresh control that's not even refreshing in the first place.  Xcode's automation does throw hissy fits about this and sleeps/timeouts won't help there.

So to fix this issue, on your main app, always check your refresh control is refreshing before ending its refresh.  I also like to check it's not nil in the first place: if you're using Swift, you can check this in one fell swoop:

```
if let refresh = self.refreshControl, refresh.refreshing {
  refresh.endRefreshing()
}
```